# error during opening websocket in IOS (CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807))

Tags: java, ios, amazon-web-services, websocket

Everything worked fine in the server two days ago. Then Suddenly IOS started not work. IOS cannot open websocket with server now. Those are the logs from IOS.

```
2020-04-04 10:51:35.122783-0300 xxxxx[5880:99324] TCP Conn 0x600000089c80 SSLHandshake failed (-9807)
2020-04-04 10:51:35.124999-0300 xxxxx[5880:99077] webSocket open error = The operation couldn’t be completed.
webSocket close code = 0, reason = (null), wasClean = 1
2020-04-04 10:51:35.604654-0300 xxxx[5880:99324] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)
2020-04-04 10:51:35.604788-0300 xxxx[5880:99324] TCP Conn 0x600000089d40 SSLHandshake failed (-9807)
2020-04-04 10:51:35.605253-0300 xxxx[5880:99077] webSocket open error = The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)
```

My Server is written by java. I use spring webscoket. 
I searched this error but I didn't find anything which would solve this problem.
And I cannot understand I must fix this in IOS or in the server.
please help me fixing this problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I fixed this problem. At first I generated new ssl certificate. Then I changed tls protocol in all nginx config files so https://libre-software.net/tls-nginx/ here you
can find how to do that.I tested and everythink is fine now.